# how to get next element from matched set?

Tags: jquery

I know about `.next()` it doesn't return the next element in matched set like iterator list. So if you say next() first item in list is given, then 2nd, and so on. But it actually finds the sibling that matches selector.

What i want to do is to get the nextItem in the list of matched elements.

```
$('p.special')
.nextItem().css('color','green')
.nextItem().css('color','blue')
.nextItem().css('color','red');
```

This should make the first p element with class special green, then second p element with class special blue and so on. Regardless of the fact that they are siblings or not.

I don't want to loop. because loop can't be controlled easily. so `each` is out of question i think. Think of this way, there is next button and user presses it. each time its pressed p.special gets its color changed one by one.

So far only way i can come up with is using `.eq`...

Comment: Why would you not want a loop? This is *exactly* what they were designed for. I don't understand your point of them not being controlled easily.

Comment: why would i not want a loop?!...simple I am trying to create a next and previous button where elements will be highlighted like in search. Then when user press next element will be colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others, I don't really know why you're avoiding a loop.

The only way I know of to get close to what you're asking is to write your own custom plug-in method and store the iteration state in the original jQuery object so each time you call the custom method, the iteration position can be retrieved from the original jQuery object:

```
jQuery.fn.nextItem = function() {
    // if no DOM objects in here, then just return an empty jQuery object
    if (!this.length) {
        return $();
    }
    var index = this._nextItemIndex || 0;
    var next = $(this[index]);
    this._nextItemIndex = (index + 1) % this.length;
    return next;
}
```

Then, you could actually do:

```
var list = $('p.special');
list.nextItem().css('color','green');
list.nextItem().css('color','blue');
list.nextItem().css('color','red');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/do3n1yf4/

You can't chain the methods because, by definition, `.nextItem()` has to return a different jQuery object than the original with only one DOM element in it, so thus you can't directly chain.

`.nextItem()` will cycle through the DOM elements in your original jQuery object, wrapping back to the first when it gets to the end.

Note that the iteration state is stored on the jQuery object `$('p.special')` so you will have to keep that specific jQuery object around in order to keep using the same state.  If you recreate `$('p.special')`, the state will be thrown away and reset back to `0`.  That state could be stored elsewhere if desired (on a DOM object, in a variable, etc...).

---

If you wanted to store the `nextItem()` state on somewhere persistent, you could store it on the `.data()` of the first DOM element in the collection:

```
jQuery.fn.nextItem = function() {
    // if no DOM objects in here, then just return an empty jQuery object
    if (!this.length) {
        return $();
    }
    var marker = $(this[0]);
    var index = marker.data("_nextItemIndex") || 0;
    var next = $(this[index]);
    marker.data("_nextItemIndex", (index + 1) % this.length);
    return next;
}

$('p.special').nextItem().css('color','green');
$('p.special').nextItem().css('color','blue');
$('p.special').nextItem().css('color','red');
```

This would allow you to recreate the jQuery object and have `.nextItem()` still work as long as the first DOM element in the collection didn't change.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bpsjou7m/

Comment: only answer that answers the question, thanks i am still miles away from learning to make jquery plugins but one day hopefully. The reason i wanted next Item is because i'm trying to make a search like functionality where items that match criteria will be highlighted and user will click next and prev to visually go through list and thus the need for nextItem etc

Comment: btw what's a different between `$(this[index])` and `$(this).eq(index)`

Comment: There is no meaningful difference between `$(this[index])` and `this.eq(index)` if you know that `index` is already bounds checked.  FYI, you don't need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object like `$(this)` inside the plugin because `this` in the plugin is already the jQuery object.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - I added one more option.

Comment: didnt know that about this, can you recommend some resource to learn about plugin development

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - you start here: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/ to learn plugins.

Answer (score 0):

A loop is *exactly* what is required here. If you store the colours you want to add in an array you can add them by using `each()`:

```js
var colours = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];
$('p.special').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('color', colours[i % colours.length]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="special">Special</p>
<p class="special">Special</p>
<p class="special">Special</p>
<p class="special">Special</p>
<p class="special">Special</p>
<p class="special">Special</p>
<p class="special">Special</p>
<p class="special">Special</p>
<p class="special">Special</p>
```

Comment: i specifically said i don't want loop... i m going to elaborate on why. I don't want loop because i don't want element to get colored right away. I want them to change color upon events from buttons like next and previous buttons

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to loop, then you can use [.css( propertyName, function)](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function). Still jQuery will use internally.

Here in example I have created an array of colors, which can be used to set colors of paragraph using its index.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];
  $('p.special').css('color', function(index) {
    return colors[index % colors.length]; 
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="special">special 1</p>
<p class="special">special 2</p>
<p class="special">special 3</p>
<p class="special">special 4</p>
<p class="special">special 5</p>
```

Comment: this is also looping in disguise, i didn't want loop to maintain control